# jQuery isotope v2 and bootstrap 3 with different item sizes

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, jquery-isotope

im using jQuery 1.10.2 with Bootstrap 3.0.3 (http://getbootstrap.com/) and Isotope v2 (http://isotope.metafizzy.co/).

I have 4 different item-sizes (col-xs-12, col-xs-6, col-xs-4, col-xs-3), these columns are mixed and defined by the user who manage the content - i can't control the order of this items. No my problem is, that isotope is using the first item-size as an reference.

This runs in an error, if the first item is "col-xs-6" and the second is smaller, than the layout is broken.

Does anybody know who to fix this issue?

best regards 
CH

Comment: Could you provide us a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/)? Or at least show us your source code.

Comment: Without isotope (Floating almost correct, but the items should be displayed all with the same gutter (Item 6,7 are wrong)): http://jsfiddle.net/aEL4n/


With isotope (The grid fails): http://jsfiddle.net/aEL4n/1/